# Why Read_HTML from Python Pandas not working?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I would like to use Python Pandas Read_HTML() function to scrape the information from Yahoo Finance table, seen in the screenshot, bordered in red.

[image]

However, I received a HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Here is my code output:

```
!pip install pandas
!pip install requests
!pip install bs4
!pip install requests_html
!pip install pytest-astropy
!pip install nest_asyncio
!pip install plotly

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import requests_html
import nest_asyncio
import lxml
import html5lib
nest_asyncio.apply()

url_link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/history?p=NFLX%27"
read_html_pandas_data = pd.read_html(url_link)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url_link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/history?p=NFLX%27'
r = requests.get(url_link,headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})
read_html_pandas_data = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
print(read_html_pandas_data)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! However, I received this output: [                                                   0
0  Will be right back...  Thank you for your pati...]

Comment: just add User-Agent

Comment: Now you will get  data

Comment: If you want to access the site's  data , then it's requirement is to get your real identification that's why you have to inject user-agent as header. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I got output, but how do I transpose the rows to columns?

Answer (score 2):

Because an user-agent header is needed which can't be specified with `read_html`. You could grab table first with `requests`, specifying the appropriate header, then handover to pandas:

```
from pandas import read_html as rh
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/history?p=NFLX%27', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = rh(str(soup.select_one('[data-test="historical-prices"]')))[0]
print(table)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Is there a way to transpose the rows to columns and place them in a DataFrame? Here is the current output:                                                Date  \
0                                         Jul 02, 2021   
1                                         Jul 01, 2021   
2                                         Jun 30, 2021

Comment: table is already a dataframe. That has a transpose() method. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html